# Drag and drop is not setting input value to be equal to files. Works if selected with the input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to create a drag and drop component. We have a working example without using a form or submit button (it is done on user input, or drag/drop).

I am modifying the component now so it will work with a form wrapper and send data to another page.

Here is the js:

```
const $fileUploader = $('.fileUploader');
const $input = $fileUploader.find('input[type="file"]');
const $label = $fileUploader.find('label');

const showFiles = files => {
    if (files) {
        $label.text(files[0].name);
    }
};

const uploadBulkReports = () => {
  $input.on('change', e => {
    showFiles(e.target.files);

  });
  $fileUploader
    .on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on('dragover dragenter', () => {
    $fileUploader.addClass('is-dragover');
  })
    .on('dragleave dragend drop', () => {
    $fileUploader.removeClass('is-dragover');
  })
    .on('drop', e => {
    droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $input.files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    showFiles(droppedFiles);
  });
};

uploadBulkReports();
```

Our HTML (I have simplified this from C#/Razor)

```
<form mvc-action="/BulkUpload/Brand" action="/BulkUpload/Brand" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="fileUploader" data-action="/BulkUpload/Brand" data-method="post">
    <div class="fileUploader__input">
      <input class="fileUploader__file" type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".csv" />
      <label for="file">Click to select a file</label>
      <p class="fileUploader__dragndrop"> or drag it here</p>
      <ul class="small">
        <li>Id: Technical id of the Brand (leave blank to create new)</li>
        <li>Name: Name of the Brand</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="fileUploader__restart fa fa-redo-alt"></a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My understanding is that on drop, the `$input.files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;` should set the input files value to the FileData information as is with the input selection. For some reason it does not work on submission.

We are only sending a single file, so I did try accessing the file here `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];` but it does not seem to work. (`e.dataTransfer.files` also does not work for me, I had to pass the `originalEvent` method).

I have made this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/75m8ocva/ although I don't think it's possible to test a form submission in jsfiddle.

I want to know if setting the `$input.files` to the dropped files is identical to setting the file input via the regular method. When I try to `console.log $input.files` after the input has changed, I get `undefined` so I assume it is a different method.

I hope someone can help, if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if setting the $input.files to the dropped files is identical to setting the file input via the regular method

No, there only one way to populate files in file upload control `<input type="file">` and that is the regular way - You click on it ; it opens you OS file browser and you select file(s)

Programatically setting files on the file upload control is not allowed due to security reasons. So that means you will have to use AJAX only.

```
.on('drop', e => {
  droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
  $input.files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; //<--this won't update file input's internal state
  showFiles(droppedFiles);
});

var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));

$.each( droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
    ajaxData.append( 'file_'+i, file );
});

$.ajax({
    data: ajaxData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) { }
});
```

But wait.. there is another sorta "hack" that many online services use when you load the page in HTML only layout or with javascript disabled. The reason why it works is that you can natively drag and drop files over a file control without any code at all giving same result had you went through the "regular way"

What they do is increase the width and height on the file control and make it look big with a label.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($('#file')[0].files)
  
});
```

```css
input[type='file'] {
  border: 2px dashed #aaa;
  padding: 100px 50px 20px 130px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow
}

input[type='file']:before {
  content: "drag & drop here";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#submit { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

<input type="file" id="file" />

<input type="submit" id="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This code that uses a pseudo before selector is a revelation to me as I was ensured that :before and :after selectors do not work with input fields. Thank you though I will try the code out soon.